# docker-machine create breaks at `DBG | Filling zeroes`

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I am trying to create the default-machine in the quickstart start.sh file, but the script hangs at `Creating SSH key...`. I've tracked it to this line in the quickstart file. `Docker Quickstart Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Scripts/start.sh`

```
$DOCKER_MACHINE create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 $VM
```

I have uninstalled everything (virtualbox, docker, docker-machine, ect.) and reinstalled the toolbox, and searched everywhere I can think of for a solution. Any ideas?

I'm on Mac OSX 10.11.2

```
❯ docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 default
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/ian/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/ian/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
^C%
>>> elapsed time 3m18s
```

Does the same with `docker-machine create -d virtualbox test`

with --debug
Does the same with `docker-machine --debug create -d virtualbox test`

```
❯ docker-machine --debug create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-memory 2048 --virtualbox-disk-size 204800 default       [10:39:11]
Docker Machine Version:  0.5.5, build
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:59530
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(flag-lookup) Calling .GetCreateFlags
Found binary path at /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
Launching plugin server for driver virtualbox
Plugin server listening at address 127.0.0.1:59534
() Calling .GetVersion
Using API Version  1
() Calling .SetConfigRaw
() Calling .GetMachineName
(default) Calling .GetMachineName
(default) Calling .DriverName
(default) Calling .GetCreateFlags
(default) Calling .SetConfigFromFlags
Running pre-create checks...
(default) Calling .PreCreateCheck
(default) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage --version
(default) DBG | STDOUT:
(default) DBG | {
(default) DBG | 5.0.12r104815
(default) DBG | }
(default) DBG | STDERR:
(default) DBG | {
(default) DBG | }
(default) DBG | local Boot2Docker ISO version:  v1.9.1
(default) DBG | COMMAND: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage list hostonlyifs
(default) DBG | STDOUT:
(default) DBG | {
(default) DBG | Name:            vboxnet0
(default) DBG | GUID:            786f6276-656e-4074-8000-0a0027000000
(default) DBG | DHCP:            Disabled
(default) DBG | IPAddress:       192.168.99.1
(default) DBG | NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
(default) DBG | IPV6Address:
(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:00
(default) DBG | MediumType:      Ethernet
(default) DBG | Status:          Down
(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet0
(default) DBG |
(default) DBG | Name:            vboxnet1
(default) DBG | GUID:            786f6276-656e-4174-8000-0a0027000001
(default) DBG | DHCP:            Disabled
(default) DBG | IPAddress:       192.168.50.1
(default) DBG | NetworkMask:     255.255.255.0
(default) DBG | IPV6Address:
(default) DBG | IPV6NetworkMaskPrefixLength: 0
(default) DBG | HardwareAddress: 0a:00:27:00:00:01
(default) DBG | MediumType:      Ethernet
(default) DBG | Status:          Down
(default) DBG | VBoxNetworkName: HostInterfaceNetworking-vboxnet1
(default) DBG |
(default) DBG | }
(default) DBG | STDERR:
(default) DBG | {
(default) DBG | }
(default) Calling .GetConfigRaw
Creating machine...
(default) Calling .Create
(default) DBG | local Boot2Docker ISO version:  v1.9.1
(default) Copying /Users/ian/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/ian/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) DBG | Creating disk image...
(default) DBG | Creating 204800 MB hard disk image...
(default) DBG | Writing magic tar header
(default) DBG | Writing SSH key tar header
(default) DBG | Calling inner createDiskImage
(default) DBG | &{/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage [/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage convertfromraw stdin /Users/ian/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk 214748364800 --format VMDK] []     []     false [] [] [] [] }
(default) DBG | Starting command
(default) DBG | Copying to stdin
(default) DBG | Converting from raw image file="stdin" to file="/Users/ian/.docker/machine/machines/default/disk.vmdk"...
(default) DBG | Creating dynamic image with size 214748364800 bytes (204800MB)...
(default) DBG | Filling zeroes
^C%
>>> elapsed time 10m46s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docker isn't actually broken, it just takes [**EXTREMELY** long to provision](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/2788) Virtual Box the first time. For my Late 2013 MacBook Pro with SSD it took ~1 hour to complete the first time.

After the initial provisioning of the default machine everything works like normal.